# Как мне одновременно выводить окно таймера и при этом каждый раз менят значение времени?

Tags: python

Я новичок в программировании.Мне нужно в данном коде как-то одновременно выводить и окно таймера,и в этом же окне таймера менять значение времени.Как мне это сделать?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

def result_window(x):
#main presets
root=Tk()
root.title('timer')
root.geometry('400x200+1515+850')
root.resizable(False, False)

# icon
icon = PhotoImage(file="timer.png")
root.iconphoto(True, icon)

count_digit=ttk.Label(root,text=x,font='Arial 15 bold')
count_digit.pack()
while x:
    count_digit.update
    time.sleep(1)
    x=x-1
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-after/